# Where to escape the string to prevent mysql injection?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering where in this code to add `$stmt ->real_escape_string($password);` in order to prevent mysql injection:

```
if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Is it after the prepare statement or before, because I've read that I must first have a connect statement before escaping, so my guess would be after the prepare statement, am I correct ?

And what else should I know about mysql injection ?

Comment: bind param always does that lol

Comment: you need escaping when "building" the `$sql` string, if you put inside data(strings) that come from "outside"; otherwise, binding is safe.

Comment: @yes123 - I didn't knew that :) So I don't need to add that escape statement, because binding will always escape ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Not a duplicate; the OP is already using prepared statements.  This question is just about the mechanics of it.  :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.

Part of what prepared statements do, is escape the data for you.  So you don't need to escape anything if you're binding it as a param.  In fact, if you did add it, you'd see backslashes and such in odd places.

The only time you'd need to use `real_escape_string`, is when you're inserting variables directly into your SQL string as values.  And if someone's doing that, they may want to double-check their understanding of the whole point of prepared statements.  :)